# Is there a simpler HTTP POST in PHP without using cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I there a simpler code to preform HTTP POST without using cURL? c

I like cURL, but it is overkill for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

This solution from Fabien Potencier seems one of the simplest one: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/20/tweeting-from-php

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via `file_get_contents()` if you supply a resource context. Check out example #4 on the function's [doc page](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising, but I haven't used it.

http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl